# Restart button in Java

Tags: java, button, restart

I have a problem with restart button in java.

I tried something like this, the game is restarted but can not start it again.

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();
    if(GameUI.flag == 2 && x > 225 && x < 381 && y > 400 && y < 493 ){
        gs.setRestart();
        gamePanel.repaint();
    }
}

public void setRestart(){
    System.out.println("");
    restart = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Buttons_01.png")).getImage();
}
```

Comment: yeah, and how do you define a game to be startable? The code provided doesn´t really tell what the cause of it is. You might want to include the starting routine aswell.

Comment: When I wrote new GameUI() opens a new window.

Comment: Start class:

`package com.iamlishuai.flappybird;

public class StartGame {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new GameUI();
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is class:
`public GameUI(){

```
    //Inicijalizacija skora na 0
    GameUI.score = 0;

    //Inicijalizacija igre
    gs = new GameStatus();

    //Inicijalizacija stanje igre
    GameUI.start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //Inicijalizacija za Audio
    player = new PlaySounds();

    //Inicijalizacija pticice
    bird = new Bird(300,200,10,5,60);

    // Inicijalizacije za cevovode
    pipe = new Pipe[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < ypoints.length; i++) {
        pipe[i] = new Pipe(x + i * GameUI.d, ypoints[i], 7);
    }

    // Igra ekrana
    gamePanel = new MyPanel(bird, pipe, gs, player);

    // Dodavanje listenera
    gamePanel.addMouseListener(this);
    gamePanel.addMouseMotionListener(this);

    //Start
    bird.start();
    player.start();
    for(int i = 0; i < pipe.length; i++){
        pipe[i].start();
    }
    Thread gp = new Thread(gamePanel);
    gp.start();

    //Setovanje i dodavanje atributa
    add(gamePanel);
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Flappy Bird - Aleksandar Kojic");
    setVisible(true);
    setBounds(10,10,800,600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}`
```